# Using OWIN app.UseCookieAuthentication how can I tell when the user has been signed in from the cookie?

Tags: events, cookies, authentication, owin

Using this I can hook up an event (OnResponseSignedIn and OnResponseSignIn) on the provider, and that works fine for when the user signs in from the form I'm using. However when the user then leaves the site and returns, I get no event as far as i can see. I preferably would like to get a SignedIn-like event so I can perform actions on the logged in user.

My code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnResponseSignedIn = (CookieResponseSignedInContext context) =>
        { 
            // do stuff here
        }
    }

});
```